# Merge 3D numpy array into 2D array

Tags: numpy

I have a numpy array of the following dimensions:

```
(2, 4, 20)
```

I'd like to merge it so that I end up with:

```
(2, 80)
```

I've tried `np.concatenate`, `np.dstack`, `np.vstack`, and `np.hstack`, but none have worked out. What should I do instead?

Comment: maybe have a look at `np.reshape`

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.reshape` function:

```
import numpy as np
A=np.random.rand(2,4,20) #creates a random narray for the example
A.shape
> (2,4,20) 
B = A.reshape(A.shape[0],A.shape[1]*A.shape[2])
B.shape
> (2,80)
```

There are different order options for reshaping, please see [reshape help](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html).